# how to add mouse event to set of divs and load data from database form click div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am doing project using Laravel 5. I make set of div according to some dynamic number. 
This is it out put.

[image]

This is code for creating above graphic.

```
 <section class="content">   
        <div class="box box-warning" align="center">
            <div class="gap">
                <div class="box-body">                
                    @foreach($rooms as $room)
                    @if($room->roomState === 'Available')
                    <div  id='divelementone' style="width:75px;height:75px;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;background-color:yellowgreen;border-radius: 5px;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;">{{$room->room_code}}</div>
                    @elseif ($room->roomState === 'UnAvailable')
                    <div  id='divelementtwo' style="width:75px;height:75px;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;background-color:red;border-radius: 5px;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;">{{$room->room_code}}</div>
                    @elseif ($room->roomState === 'notCheckIn')
                    <div  id='divelementthree' style="width:75px;height:75px;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;background-color:yellow;border-radius: 5px;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;">{{$room->room_code}}</div>   

                    @endif
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.box --> 
</section><!-- /.content -->
```

now I want to attach every div(square) elements to mouse click event. when mouse over the div , change mouse pointer and get some database value specific id and also, I want to view  that value in tool tip or some suitable panel over the div(Square).

I try using JavaScript  to attach mouse click event ,but it work only with first div(square).

I am new comer to web development so , I haven't knowledge ,how to handle this requirement. please , expect some expert help as soon as possible.

**Note :
My main purpose is attach mouse click events to every div and load datafrom db and view them tooltip or optionpane.**

Comment: `div:hover { background: red; }`?

Comment: @Tushar whare i  should put this code ? do you have any idea attach mouse click event to every div and load data from data base ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Attach JavaScript `onclick()` event to every div.

***In View***(blade)

```
<div class="box-body">                
      @foreach($rooms as $room)
       @if($room->roomState === 'Available')
         <div onclick="divClick('Available', {{$room->room_code}})" id='divelementone' style="width:75px;height:75px;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;background-color:yellowgreen;border-radius: 5px;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;">{{$room->room_code}}</div>
       @elseif ($room->roomState === 'UnAvailable')
         <div onclick="divClick('UnAvailable', {{$room->room_code}})" id='divelementtwo' style="width:75px;height:75px;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;background-color:red;border-radius: 5px;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;">{{$room->room_code}}</div>
       @elseif ($room->roomState === 'notCheckIn')
         <div onclick="divClick('notCheckIn', {{$room->room_code}})" id='divelementthree' style="width:75px;height:75px;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;background-color:yellow;border-radius: 5px;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;">{{$room->room_code}}</div>   
       @endif
      @endforeach    
</div>
```

***In JavaScript***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function divClick(roomState, roomCode)
  {
    // Your code here
    // Ajax code for fetching data from DB


    // Alert the passed room code like this
    window.alert(roomCode);
  }
</script>
```

To change mouse pointer use CSS styling `div:hover { cursor:pointer; }`. Also it would a best practice to link a separate CSS file for the div styling.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: ya it is helpful .Thank for your help . now when click the div it will called that function.Do you have any idea about data loading with in the javascript.?

Comment: You could  send a AJAX request to fetch values from DB and use this AJAX response for data loading.. What data are you trying to load ? ?

Comment: thank sir , I will try it. I want to get mysql database table value , related to roomCode, and value visible as tooltip or optionpane.

Comment: ,I want to pass room code value to javascript.but I put {{$room->roomCode}} in to divClick.  e.g divClick('notCheckIn', {{$room->roomCode}}); but pass error. value is not defined. ?

Comment: onclick="divClick( 'notCheckIn', {{$room->room_code}} );"  Please check the comma's and quotes. If you are sure that $room->room_code is not null then i believe then it would be a syntax error ... I can see that you have given $room->roomCode instead of $room->room_code.. Please double check on that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33538014/pass-specific-data-value-from-div-to-javascript-in-laravel-5-0?noredirect=1#comment54856988_33538014 I will post it as different question for more understanding.

Comment: You should give $room->room_code instead of $room->roomcode. In your question above you have given as {{ $room->room_code }}.. Pls check it.

Comment: alert the value like this window.alert(roomCode);

Comment: ,I will change it but still same error. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33538014/pass-specific-data-value-from-div-to-javascript-in-laravel-5-0?noredirect=1#comment54856988_33538014

Comment: Check the Updated answer above i have modified my answer

Comment: I will make changes , but still same out put.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div class="box-body">                
      @foreach($rooms as $room)
         <div onclick="divClick({{$room->roomState}}), {{$room->room_code}})" id='divelementone' style="width:75px;height:75px;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;background-color:yellowgreen;border-radius: 5px;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;">{{$room->room_code}}</div>
      @endforeach    
</div>
```