# pass specific data value from div to javascript in Laravel 5.0?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

My view as separate divs(square) , made by given integer from database .This is front end view.I want when i click this div pass , it code(roomID) to JavaScript function.

[image]

This is my current code.

```
    <section class="content">   
        <div class="box box-warning" align="center">
            <div class="gap">
                <div class="box-body" id="panel">                
                    @foreach($rooms as $room)
                    @if($room->roomState === 'Available')
                    <div onclick="divClick('Available',1);"  id='divelementone' style="width:75px;height:75px;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;background-color:yellowgreen;border-radius: 5px;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;cursor:pointer;">{{$room->room_code}}</div>
                    @elseif ($room->roomState === 'UnAvailable')
                    <div onclick="divClick('UnAvailable', 2);" id='divelementtwo' style="width:75px;height:75px;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;background-color:red;border-radius: 5px;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;cursor:pointer;">{{$room->room_code}}</div>
                    @elseif ($room->roomState === 'notCheckIn')
                    <div onclick="divClick('notCheckIn', 3);" id='divelementthree' style="width:75px;height:75px;border:1px solid #000;display:inline-block;background-color:yellow;border-radius: 5px;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;cursor:pointer;">{{$room->room_code}}</div>   

                    @endif
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.box --> 
</section><!-- /.content -->
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function divClick(roomState, roomCode)
  {
    //  Your code here


   window.alert(roomCode);
  }
</script>
```

This is working fine. I change to `divClick('UnAvailable', 2);` code to `divClick('UnAvailable', {{$room->room_code}});` pass this error.

```
ReferenceError: roomcode is not defined
```

want some expert help resolve this.

=================after correct comment mistake give this error. ======================

```
ReferenceError: H5003 is not defined
```

[image]

Comment: @RayonDabre i am new comer to web development. so , I am hart to understand what you are saying, please , could you post some answer?

Comment: Can you provide `processed` html ? That will help!

Comment: try `window.alert(roomCode);`

Comment: @madalinivascu, I was going somewhere else :P

Comment: Remove the qoutes around '{{$room->room_code}}' ... {{$room->room_code}} is only needed

Comment: @ArtisanBay pass this error . ReferenceError: H5003 is not defined 5:1:1
ReferenceError: H5001 is not defined . when i click div , error console print this .

Comment: Instead of window.alert could your please try alert(roomCode);

Comment: @ArtisanBay still same out put. when i click div , print above error.(I put error console image )

Comment: I think it is a conflict between different JS libs. In the above image I can see an error of unreachable code.

Comment: @ArtisanBay sir , when i change code like this , divClick('UnAvailable', 2); it will show me out put as 2 ???

Comment: Well then, could you try this  divClick('UnAvailable', '{{ $room->room_code }}');

Comment: @ArtisanBay , now it is ok....! I will put your above code. Thank lot of your help.Now, I will mark your other question answer as acceptable.

Comment: No problem. Happy that you found the solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript ReferenceError is not defined

I believe this happens due to the conflict between various JS libraries included in your project and their dependencies with each other:

***Your options:***

1) Please check if all the JS lib's are loaded in proper order

2) Add a wrap around function to escape `undefined` values

```
if((typeof varName) != 'undefined') {
   alert(varName);        
}
```

Ex: jQuery lib should be called first and then all the dependent JS libs.

In most cases and easy fix would be make a call to `noConflict()` to restore the variable.

Add `$.noConflict();` just above the document ready in script.

A good reference [docs](https://tommcfarlin.com/javascript-reference-error-is-not-defined/)

Hope this is helpful.